# implementation for java substring with negative values

Tags: java, string, substring

in java,

```
String month= "November 2014";
```

for making a substring giving the index from right hand side, I cannot use

```
someString.substring(-4);
```

as negative values are not supported.

Is there any simple implementation I can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, negative numbers are not allowed (it would throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`). You can use this:

```
if(month.length() >= 4) {
    year = month.substring(month.length() - 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I love Python's indexing and prefer to be able to use it in Java as well ;)

A general implementation of substring with support for negative indexing could be implemented like this:

A method for converting negative indexes to their positive equivalent is useful:

```
private static int toPosIndex(String str, int index) {
    if (index >= 0) return index;
    else return str.length() + index;
```

This method can then be used to declare a substring method with support for negative indexes:

```
public static String negSubstring(String str, int index1, int index2) {
    return str.substring(toPosIndex(str, index1), toPosIndex(str, index2));
}
```

and if needed an equivalent to the version of substring with only one index parameter:

```
public static String negSubstring(String str, int index) {
    return str.substring(toPosIndex(str, index));
}
```

(I realise the question is more than two years old, but figured that other new users might be interested in a general answer to the question).